# Worst Case for AVL Tree Balancing after Deletion

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, time-complexity, balanced-search-trees, avl-trees

After deleting a node in an **AVL** tree, self-balancing (zig-zag rotation or the left-right balancing) maintains **O(logn)** time that is not guaranteed in other unbalanced trees (like BST).

The Balancing operation is said to be **O(logn)**.

What is the worst case for balancing? (I guess it will require balancing at every node all the way up till the root)

***Any specific type of tree providing the worst case?***

Comment: We know that the worst case can't be worse than $O(\log n)$ because it does a constant amount of operations at each level towards the root, and there are at most $O(\log n)$ levels up towards the root. We don't usually care to find an explicit example since we've already proven it can't get worse.

Answer (score 4):

To make a lot of rebalancing, you would like to make your AVL tree as imbalanced as possible. And the worst case is a Fibonnachi-like tree:
[image]

, where $T_n$ is a tree with $T_{n-1}$ as a left child and $T_{n-2}$ as a right child ($T_1=T_2=$single-node tree).

On this example, if you remove `19`, then node `18` must be rebalanced. After that, node `13` must be rebalanced. Essentially, you will have a rebalance at every level above node `20`. You can build an arbitrary large such tree. I didn't check, but it should be simple to prove that removing the rightmost node always suffices for the worst case.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, got it!